# Closing and opening new view controllers directly after each other swift 3

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I do not have a problem for you to solve. I would just like some clarity. First, let me explain what I am doing.

I have a viewcontroller than makes a call to a PHP script to retrieve json. While this is processing, I have an activityViewController displayed showing the progress. Directly after this is retrieved another call is made to email the data. Before the email call is made the activityViewController is closed and a new one is opened in the new function, showing the progress of the emailing process. Once that is done, an alert is displayed.

All of this works, but I had to do something in order to have the viewcontrollers move over to the next without the "Warning: attempt to present [ViewController] on [ViewController] while already presenting". I had to add a delay in the code to allow the previous viewcontroller to close successfully before the next attempts to open. Like I said, this is working smoothly, and the delay is 0.3 seconds. Quite fast.

What I want to know however, could it MAYBE happen that the viewcontroller will close slowly on certain devices, running past the 0.3 seconds and then throwing the error?

I would just like to learn here.. :)

ANY information is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to use completion handlers after presenting or dismissing view controllers. If use it then your view controllers will get rid of those warnings and your controllers will appear thick and fast without any timers.

`aViewController.dismiss(animated: true) {
    viewController.present(anotherViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}`

Comment: Well deserved accepted answer! Thank you! Looks exactly like my "Delay", but at least I know it will work on all devices! ;)